# Trying to sort dynamically rendered divs based on values in data passed through

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I have a `dict` like so:

```
choices = {'Mexico': 53, 'Panama': 1, 'Honduras': 8} // data passed through
```

HTML:

```
<div class="poll">
    <div class="poll_div">
    <h1><strong>Question?</strong></h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="poll_form"> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bMfVv1HAB9PcivrMZfP5dZddKCXt7xBCxv6WGHqpcw6cT1bNIfKjGPNIK74hGCkF' />


        <div class="poll_choice_div">

            <div class="poll_choice">
                <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1"/>Mexico<br>
            </div>

            <div class="poll_choice">
                <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2"/>Panama<br>
            </div>

            <div class="poll_choice">
                <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3"/>Honduras<br>
            </div>

        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Vote" />

    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="poll_results">

        <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="14">
            <p class="choice_result_text">Mexico</p>
            <span>14%</span>
        </div>

        <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="24">
            <p class="choice_result_text">Panama</p>
            <span>24%</span>
        </div>

        <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="60">
            <p class="choice_result_text">Honduras</p>
            <span>60%</span>
        </div>

    <p class="total_votes">Total Votes: 0</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery (ajax call)

```
$('.poll_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);

    ...

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/poll_answer/',
        data: {
            answer: choice,
            question: question,
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            result = $form.parent().parent().find('.choice_result_text');
            choices = data.choices; // {the dictionary}

            $('.choice_result').each(function() { // Add value to choice
                var key = $(this).find('.choice_result_text').text();
                if (key in choices) {
                    $(this).find('.choice_result_text').next().text(choices[key] + '%');
                  }
            }).sort(function(a, b) { // Now sort them
              return choices[$(b).find('.choice_result_text').text()] - choices[$(a).find('.choice_result_text').text()];
            }).appendTo('body');


            $('.total_votes').html('Total votes: ' + data.total_votes)
        }
    })


});
```

What this currently does is change the `span` to the `val` of the `key` in `choices`. This works fine, but I want to sort the divs based on the `val` (in descending order). So instead the divs should be sorted as `Mexico, Honduras, Panama`. As there is no way to sort `dictionaries`, I need to find another way to do this.

Comment: The order of keys in an object literal is not defined so you'll need to define order in another way (hint, use an array)

Comment: That's kind of what i'm asking, for someone to use this same method but use an array instead. I tried myself and struggled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have change the `choice` dictionary, you can *sort* the DOM elements itself.

*Sort* the divs based on the value and afterwards *append* them back to the DOM - see demo below:

```js
// data obtained from ajax call
var choices = {
  'Mexico': 53,
  'Panama': 1,
  'Honduras': 8
}

$('.poll').each(function() {

  $(this).find('.choice_result').each(function() { // Add value to choice
    var key = $(this).find('.choice_result_text').text();
    if (key in choices) {
      $(this).find('.choice_result_text').next().text(choices[key] + '%');
    }
  }).sort(function(a, b) { // Now sort them
    return choices[$(b).find('.choice_result_text').text()] - choices[$(a).find('.choice_result_text').text()];
  }).appendTo($(this).find('.poll_results'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="poll">
  <div class="poll_div">
    <h1><strong>Question?</strong></h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="poll_form">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bMfVv1HAB9PcivrMZfP5dZddKCXt7xBCxv6WGHqpcw6cT1bNIfKjGPNIK74hGCkF' />


      <div class="poll_choice_div">

        <div class="poll_choice">
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" />Mexico
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="poll_choice">
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" />Panama
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="poll_choice">
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3" />Honduras
          <br>
        </div>

      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Vote" />

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="poll_results">

    <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="14">
      <p class="choice_result_text">Mexico</p>
      <span>14%</span>
    </div>

    <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="24">
      <p class="choice_result_text">Panama</p>
      <span>24%</span>
    </div>

    <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="60">
      <p class="choice_result_text">Honduras</p>
      <span>60%</span>
    </div>

    <p class="total_votes">Total Votes: 0</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="poll">
  <div class="poll_div">
    <h1><strong>Question?</strong></h1>
    <form action="" method="post" class="poll_form">
      <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='bMfVv1HAB9PcivrMZfP5dZddKCXt7xBCxv6WGHqpcw6cT1bNIfKjGPNIK74hGCkF' />


      <div class="poll_choice_div">

        <div class="poll_choice">
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice1" />Mexico
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="poll_choice">
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice2" />Panama
          <br>
        </div>

        <div class="poll_choice">
          <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice3" />Honduras
          <br>
        </div>

      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Vote" />

    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="poll_results">

    <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="14">
      <p class="choice_result_text">Mexico</p>
      <span>14%</span>
    </div>

    <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="24">
      <p class="choice_result_text">Panama</p>
      <span>24%</span>
    </div>

    <div class="choice_result" data-choice_percent="60">
      <p class="choice_result_text">Honduras</p>
      <span>60%</span>
    </div>

    <p class="total_votes">Total Votes: 0</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok so the `$.each()` is working fine but the `.sort()` for some reason deletes all the divs....If I take away `.appendTo('body') then it won't delete them

Comment: the snippet works fine, your actual HTML is different?

Comment: Yes i'll post the actual html

Comment: @Zorgan see the edited answer - the change is in `.appendTo('.poll_results')`

Comment: Ok so the sorting and everything is working but i've got a slight problem if you could help. I have multiple `.poll`s on my page so there are multiple `.poll_form`s. This adds the `.choice_result` divs from those other polls every time I submit a form. So I tried to change it by setting `var current = $(this);` before the success function. And then do `current.find($('.choice_result')).each(function() { // Add value to choice`. But this is still appending those other choice divs from seperate `.poll`s. Any idea? I will mark the answer correct anyway because it is a good solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Zorgan added another `each()` for `.poll` and edited the jquery accordingly... Guess this is what you were stuck at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135657/discussion-between-zorgan-and-kukkuz).

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```js
choices = {'Mexico': 53, 'Panama': 1, 'Honduras': 8};

sorted = Object.keys(choices).sort();

for (var place of sorted)
  {
    // do stuff
    console.log(place, " number: ", choices[place]);
  }
```

What this does is get the keys of the object and turn them into an array, which you then sort (puts it into order) and then use the ordered keys to get your values.

Comment: Getting a `Let definitions are not currently supported by the current Javascript version` error

Comment: change it to var, not having anything in front of it probably works too

Answer (score 0):

```js
let choices = {'Mexico': 53, 'Panama': 1, 'Honduras': 8} // data passed through
let arr = Object.keys(choices).map((k) => {
  return {
    place: k,
    val: choices[k]
  }
});
arr.sort( function(a,b) {
  return b.val - a.val;  
});


html = '';
arr.forEach( (obj) => {
  html += `
<div class="choice_result">
    <p class="choice_result_text">${obj.place}</p>
    <span></span>
</div>
`;
});
console.log(html);
```